# Case statement greater than sign in else part in SQL

Tags: sql-server-2012

Cannot you <= sign in case else or then part

```
SELECT
    INSTALLMENTDATE,
    CASE 
       WHEN EMISTATUS = 0 THEN ''
       WHEN EMISTATUS = 1 THEN CONVERT(DATETIME, INSTALLMENTDATE -2, 103) 
            <= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2019-09-15', 120)
FROM
    LOANSCHEDULEDETAILS
```

Comment: `CASE` is an **expression** (not a statement)  - like `a+b`, which returns one single, atomic value - and it has to be terminated by an `END` - not at all clear what you're trying to do a comparison with here.....

Comment: Just wanted to know if i can use <= sign in then part of the case statement..

Comment: No you can't - again, since `CASE` is **NOT** a statement - it's an **expression** that returns a value. You cannot use `CASE` for flow control in your program -

Comment: Okay Thank you :)

Comment: you could `WHEN  EMISTATUS = 1 AND CONVERT(DATETIME, INSTALLMENTDATE -2, 103) >= GETDATE() THEN 'whatever'`

Comment: @marc_s The question is poorly written/hard to understand but I guess it could `(case condition then value1 else value2 end) >= valueToCompare`